# Is the subset $X:=\{x \in C^2([0,1]) | x(0)=x(1)=0 \}$ of the Banach space $C^m ([0,1])$ also a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

To prove this statement I planned to use the fact that every closed linear subspace of a Banach space is also a Banach space. Therefore I only have to show that $X$ is a linear subspace, which it was easy to see, and that $X$ is closed (i.e, if $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $x_n \to x$, then $x \in X$).

I can prove that $x(0)=x(1)=0$, but I am stuck at showing that $x$ is twice differentiable. I would appreciate a hint for solving this.

edit: This has to be shown for any integer $m \geq 0$.

edit2: This is respect to the norm $||x||_{C^m} := \sum_{k=0}^m \text{sup}_{t\in[0,1]}|x^{(k)}(t)|$, where $x^{(k)}$ means the $k$-th derivative of $x \in C^m([0,1])$.

Comment: Is $m \geq 2$? If so, then if $x_n \to x$ in $C^m([0,1])$ automatically implies that $x$ is $C^2$.

Comment: $X \subset C^m([0,1])$ holds only for $m \leq 2$. In any case, $C^2([0,1])$ is a Banach space with norm $||x||_{C^2} = ||x||_\infty + ||x'||_\infty + ||x''||_\infty$ and evaluation at point is continuous in $C^2([0,1])$, hence $X$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Considering $X$ as a subset of $C^m([0,1])$ for $m = 0,1$, it follows that this is not closed in the subspace topology. Indeed, $\bar{X} = \{ f \in C^m([0,1]), f(0) = f(1) = 0\}$ because the polynomials are dense in $C^m([0,1])$.

Comment: Is this wrt. $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm or $\|f\|=\sum_{k=0}^m \|f^{(k)}\|_\infty$ norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $X$ must be closed, since uniform convergence does not respect differentiability. More formally, take some $0<a<b<c<d<1$ and let $f$ be a smooth bump function that is 1 on $[b,c]$ and 0 outside of $[a,d]$. Now, by the Stone Weierstrass theorem, we can find a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ converging uniformly to any continuous function $g: [a,d]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$. For all $n$, $p_n f\in X$. In fact, they are all smooth. Furthermore, $p_n f \to gf$, and on $[b,c]$ we have $gf=g$. If we take $g$ to be $C^1$ but not $C^2$ on $[b,c]$, then we have exhibited a sequence $p_n f \in X$ that converges in $C^1([0,1])$ to a limit not in $X$.

Comment: I had the same thought but the hint to prove that $X$ is closed was given by the professor and that confuses me.

Comment: That's strange. I don't see a flaw in my proof but I'm not very knowledgeable on functional analysis so perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: The proof that paul blart math cop gave is correct. I think there is something wrong with the problem formulation as presented here, if $X$ is supposed to be a Banach subspace of $C^m([0,1])$ for all $m \geq 0$. Otherwise, see my comments above.

Comment: I tried this: let $\lim_{n \to \infty} x'_n = g$ and $0<a<b<1$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n(b) - x_n(a)) = x(b) - x(a) =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b x'_n(t)dt$, now by the Dominated Convergence Theorem this is equal to $\int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty} x'_n(t)dt = \int_a^b g(t)dt$. So by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculous $g = x'$, i.e, $x$ is at least $C^1([0,1])$. And I think that a similar procedure can be done to see that $x \in C^2([0,1])$. What do you think?

Comment: I think the issue here is that you have begun your argument by assuming that the derivatives $x_n'$ converge to some $g$ at all. With this, it does work.

Comment: I see... thank you very much for your response. I'll leave it some time unsolved to see if someone has anything else to say.

Comment: Glad I could help!